# Using a function in dplyr filter

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I'd like to define a helper function to help me compose some boolean filters more clearly.

This is a working example of the result using the `iris` dataset

```
library(tidyverse)


sepal_config = function(length, width, species, .data) {
  .data$Sepal.Length > length & .data$Sepal.Width < width & .data$Species == species
}

iris %>% 
  filter(
      sepal_config(length = 4, width = 3, species = "versicolor", .data = .data) |  # 34 rows
      sepal_config(length = 3, width = 3, species = "virginica",  .data = .data)    # 21 rows
    )                                                                               # 55 rows
```

I want to do this without having to pass in `.data`, and ideally to also have the column names evaluated in the dataframe scope (i.e., avoiding this error)

```
sepal_config = function(length, width, species) {
  Sepal.Length > length & Sepal.Width < width & Species == species
}

iris %>% 
  filter(
      sepal_config(length = 4, width = 3, species = "versicolor") |
      sepal_config(length = 3, width = 3, species = "virginica")
    )
```

```
Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
ℹ Input `..1` is `|...`.
x object 'Sepal.Length' not found
```

Unfortunately I don't understand NSE well enough to know if this is an option. I have tried various techniques from the [programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) how-to guide, but the footnote makes me think I am looking in the wrong place.

> dplyr’s `filter()` is inspired by base R’s `subset()`. `subset()` provides data masking, but not with tidy evaluation, so the techniques described in this chapter don’t apply to it.

Thanks,
Akhil

Comment: All the `dplyr` functions `filter`, `summarise`, `mutate`, `group_by` have data as first argument. Why do you want to avoid that ? How do you expect to get `Sepal.Length` etc value from data if you wish to avoid it. Or do you just want to avoid calling `.data$` repeatedly ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap the expression in your function with `quo()` and use the `!!` operator to defuse it in the `filter()` call.

```
library(dplyr)

sepal_config = function(length, width, species) {
  quo(Sepal.Length > length & Sepal.Width < width & Species == species)
  }

iris %>% 
  filter(!!sepal_config(length = 4, width = 3, species = "versicolor") |
         !!sepal_config(length = 3, width = 3, species = "virginica"))


   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
1           5.5         2.3          4.0         1.3 versicolor
2           6.5         2.8          4.6         1.5 versicolor
3           5.7         2.8          4.5         1.3 versicolor
4           4.9         2.4          3.3         1.0 versicolor
5           6.6         2.9          4.6         1.3 versicolor
6           5.2         2.7          3.9         1.4 versicolor
7           5.0         2.0          3.5         1.0 versicolor
8           6.0         2.2          4.0         1.0 versicolor
9           6.1         2.9          4.7         1.4 versicolor
10          5.6         2.9          3.6         1.3 versicolor
...
```

Answer (score 4):

`dplyr` provides a function `cur_data()` for this sort of thing:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

sepal_config <- function(data, length, width, species, .data = cur_data()) {
  .data$Sepal.Length > length & .data$Sepal.Width < width & .data$Species == species
}

iris %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  filter(
    sepal_config(length = 4, width = 3, species = "versicolor") |  # 34 rows
      sepal_config(length = 3, width = 3, species = "virginica")    # 21 rows
  )     
#> # A tibble: 55 x 5
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species   
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>     
#>  1          5.5         2.3          4           1.3 versicolor
#>  2          6.5         2.8          4.6         1.5 versicolor
#>  3          5.7         2.8          4.5         1.3 versicolor
#>  4          4.9         2.4          3.3         1   versicolor
#>  5          6.6         2.9          4.6         1.3 versicolor
#>  6          5.2         2.7          3.9         1.4 versicolor
#>  7          5           2            3.5         1   versicolor
#>  8          6           2.2          4           1   versicolor
#>  9          6.1         2.9          4.7         1.4 versicolor
#> 10          5.6         2.9          3.6         1.3 versicolor
#> # ... with 45 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>